# zookeeper gives an unknownhostexception

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am configuring three mesos masters and am now setting up zookeeper.
zoo.cfg:

```html
server.1=cersei-master1:2888:3888
server.2=tywin-master2:2888:3888
server.3=jaime-master3:2888:3888
maxClientCnxns=50
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

zookeeper log on cersei-master1:

```html
2016-03-25 06:09:59,547 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumCnxManager@368] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address tywin-master2:3888
java.net.UnknownHostException: tywin-master2
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:354)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:388)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:765)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:716)
2016-03-25 06:09:59,548 [myid:1] - WARN  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:QuorumCnxManager@368] - Cannot open channel to 3 at election address jaime-master3:3888
java.net.UnknownHostException: jaime-master3
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectOne(QuorumCnxManager.java:354)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumCnxManager.connectAll(QuorumCnxManager.java:388)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.FastLeaderElection.lookForLeader(FastLeaderElection.java:765)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.run(QuorumPeer.java:716)
2016-03-25 06:09:59,548 [myid:1] - INFO  [QuorumPeer[myid=1]/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:2181:FastLeaderElection@774] - Notification time out: 60000
```

my hostnames are in /etc/hosts

```html
127.0.0.1   cersei-master1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```

I've alse set the zoo.cfg with the ip's and 0.0.0.0 for the current node. Nothing there. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you ping `tywin-master2` and `jaime-master3`?

Comment: yes i can ping them both

Comment: Sorry, I meant can you ping them from `cersei-master1`?

Comment: yes, they can all ping to eachother

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when i tried running the zookeeper in the cluster mode. I was using centos 7 OS. If you are using the same. Try flushing the Iptables

```
iptables -F
```

and restart the zookeeper. It will start.

Comment: I experienced something similar in Kubernetes; the headless service which creates A records does so after ZK has started.  By restarting the pod, the issue was resolved.